# What was done to improve the safety of jousts after the death of Henry II?

Tags: sports, renaissance

While jousting in a tournament to celebrate his daughter's marriage in 1559, France's Henry II received a splinter in the eye, and died not long afterwards. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_II_of_France#Death), this marked the death of jousting in France, but the practice continued in other countries.

What improvements to the safety of jousts were investigated and made in response to Henry's death? How widespread was their adoption?

Comment: I don't think they began by establishing of committee of inquiry tasked with preparing a whitepaper.

Comment: Actually it seems like it might have.  Apparently the committee came to the conclusion, "mang it's really not smart to have people charge at each other with sharpened poles, we should probably not do it or something".

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for France, but in England the tilts continued.

People often forget that Henry VIII had been very handsome indeed before his legs, crushed and stinking from a jousting accident, made him so miserable and in turn, cruel to others.

But, it was great spectacle and sport!

You might like [Jousting History](http://www.history.co.uk/shows/full-metal-jousting/articles/history-of-jousting) & [more about Henry VIII](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2789029/); also [illuminated manuscripts of tilts & jousts](http://lj.rossia.org/users/marinni/289353.html?thread=2650185).

Comment: While colorful, this does not answer the question asked.

Comment: ...also [A Knight's Tale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Knight's_Tale)